# Missing QMenuBar in Qt4 apps on OSX

Tags: macos, qt4

My Qt4 apps with a QMenuBar show up fine under Linux and Windows, but will not display under OSX. I have a Xeon 64bit Mac Pro with OSX 10.5.7. I'm using Qt 4.5.2. I've tried building my apps with qmake -spec macx-g++ and using an xcode project. Neither seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Regis

Answer (score 3):

Your menu should be displayed in the top-level Mac menu. A full desktop screenshot and a code sample would help.

Comment: Ha! Well, I feel pretty stupid.  I'm brand new to Macs so I overlooked this obvious solution. Thanks!

Comment: You should set this answer as accepted, it increases our reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

> **QMenuBar on Mac OS X**
>
> QMenuBar on Mac OS X is a wrapper for using the system-wide menu bar. If you have multiple menu bars in one dialog the outermost menu bar (normally inside a widget with widget flag Qt::Window) will be used for the system-wide menu bar.

[QMenuBar documentation](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qmenubar.html#details)